# Noetherian, Artinian on graded ring and localization

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian, graded-rings, artinian

There's an exercise in Tom Marley's [Graded Rings and Modules](https://www.math.unl.edu/~tmarley1/905notes.pdf) making me confused, stating

> $R$ is a nonnegatively graded local ring with $R_0$ being local. Let $M$ be the unique homogeneous maximal ideal Prove $R_M$ Artinian (Noetherian) implies $R$ Artinian (Noetherian).

This may be an easy question. But I can't solve it since I still don't see the connection between localization and Artinity of $R$. Any ideas

Answer (score -1):

For Artinian case, It is result of Exercises 4.7, and 2.10:
 Take a descending chain of *homogeneous* ideals in $R$ and localize at the *homogeneous maximal* ideal, $M$. Now use 2.10.

For Noetherian case replace 4.7 with 4.3

Comment: What is the idea here?

Comment: @chítrungchâu The idea is very simple, but you have to run within the Marley notes in order to understand this terse answer: The ring $R$ is Artinian/Noetherian iff satisfies DCC/ACC on homogeneous ideals (see the exercises 4.7/4.3). Now such a chain of homogeneous ideals must stop in $R_M$ (since it is Artinian/Noetherian), so you got some homogeneous ideals $I\subseteq J$ such that $I_M=J_M$. Now conclude $I=J$ from exercise 2.10, so the chains also stop in $R$.

Comment: @user26857 Since op have not noted any try, I only post a terse answer (as hint). It is common in the site to do so, isnt it?

Comment: @chí trung châu didnt get the idea?